# Problem with running flask app in python 3.7 on windows

Tags: python, windows, flask, python-3.7

I am following a python course on web development and flask... i set-up flask on my pc and then run my file i had named it server.py...it gave me a error you have not given a environment variable FLASK_RUN and there is no app.py or wsgi.py in it .
i saw tutorials and found out i had to name the file app.py so i did that and run it worked!

later on i changed the code a bit instead of 'hello!' to 'i am learning flask..' i closed the server and restarted it through cmd (not reloading the page)!!it kept showing my old code 'hello!' and not 'i am learning flask'...

here is my code before...

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return 'hello!'
if __name__=='__main__':
     app.run()
```

and after...

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return 'i am learning flask'
if __name__=='__main__':
     app.run()
```

that's it! am i doing anything wrong in setting up flask??

1. set new venv
2. activate venv
3. install flask
4. make a file (app.py)
5. set variable in cmd:  set FLASK_APP = app.py
6. add some code in it
7. run it by typing: flask run(i got a error but i fixed it by setting variable)
8. go to http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (i think it is same for all?)

that's it?

i am using python 3.7
and on windows! most if not all tutorials ended up being on mac even the course!

help will be appreciated

thanks..

Answer (score 0):

You need to rerun the app or run it in debug mode like

```py
app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: do you mean i rerun the app in the browser?

Comment: what do you mean by rerun? you mean in the browser or cmd??

Comment: Rerun from `cmd`.